# Reorder ggplot axis by one value, display labels from another

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Situation is as follows:
I have many *names* and many corresponding *codes* for those names.
All different names have a unique code, but not all different codes have a unique name.

This has created an issue when plotting the data, as I need to `group_by(code)`, and `reorder(name,code)` when plotting, but the codes are nonsense and I want to display the names. Since some codes share names, this creates a bit of an issue.

Example to illustrate below:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

# example df
df <- tibble("name" = c('apple','apple','pear','pear','pear',
                        'orange','banana','peach','pie','soda',
                        'pie','tie','beer','picnic','cigar'),
             "code" = seq(1,15),
             "value" = round(runif(15,0,100)))
```

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(name,value)))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=value),
           stat='identity')+
  coord_flip()+
  ggtitle("The axis labels I want, but the order I don't")
```

[image: plot example 1]

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(code,value)))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=value),
           stat='identity')+
  coord_flip()+
  ggtitle("The order I want, but the axis labels I don't")
```

[image]

---

Not quite sure how to get ggplot to keep the display and order of the second plot while being able to replace the axis labels with the names from the first plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `interaction` to bind names and code and in `scale_x_discrete` replace labels by appropriate one such as follow:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=interaction(reorder(name, value),reorder(code,value))))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=value),
             stat='identity')+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) sub("\\..*$","",x), name = "name")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes I think it is, took a minute to work it out but this is the format I was looking for, thanks! Unfortunately my actual `name` entries contain punctuation, so now I'll need to lookup how to remove from right to left until the first period.